# How do you calculate the rate of rotation using the accelerometer values in Android for a particular axis?

Tags: android, physics

I am developing a simple game which involves a character moving up and down only along the Y axis.

Currently I am using the accelerometer readings to change the Y velocity of the character. The game works fine but the biggest problem is that you have to keep the device horizontal in order to play the game properly.

What I really want is to change the characters Y velocity only when there is a change in the rate of rotation along the Y axis. I need to be able to translate this rate of change into the Y velocity of the character. In this way it will not matter how much the device is tilted and the user can play the game while holding the device normally.

Since the accelerometer is mandatory in every device, therefore older devices can run my game I want to be able to calculate this rate of change using the data retrieved from the accelerometer.

I found a link which explains how to get pitch and roll from accelerometer data. I used the exact code and came up with this,

```
final double alpha = 0.5;
double fXg = 0;
double fYg = 0;
double fZg = 0;
fXg = game.getInput().getAccelX() * alpha + (fXg * (1.0 - alpha));
fYg = game.getInput().getAccelY() * alpha + (fYg * (1.0 - alpha));
fZg = game.getInput().getAccelZ() * alpha + (fZg * (1.0 - alpha));
double pitch = (Math.atan2(-fYg, fZg) * 180.0) / Math.PI;
double roll = (Math.atan2(fXg, Math.sqrt(fYg * fYg + fZg * fZg)) * 180.0) / Math.PI;
pitch = (pitch >= 0) ? (180 - pitch) : (-pitch - 180);
```

With this piece of code I am unable grasp how to calculate the RATE of change.

Am I going in the right direction with this or is this completely different from what I want?

Also is it better if I just use the gyroscope instead of relying on the accelerometer?

Thanx in advance.